# How to select exactly Username and password paying attention uppercase and lowercase letters - mysql

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause, uppercase, lowercase

In this case i've created "logins" table:

```
+--------+--------------+---------+-----+
|ID_LOGIN| USERNAME     | PASSWORD      |
+--------+--------------+---------+-----+
| 1      | admin        | admin         | 
+--------+--------------+---------------+
| 2      | MaxiKIng1991 | #MaxiKIng1991$|
+--------+--------------+---------------+
```

I'm going to select all where username and password is specified. But i'd like **pay attention to uppercase and lowercase letters**. So please take a look. First i selected first login (username and password).

```
SELECT * FROM `logins` WHERE USERNAME = "AdMin" AND PASSWORD = "AdMin";
```

When i wrote this query it shows like this:

```
+--------+--------------+---------+-----+
|ID_LOGIN| USERNAME     | PASSWORD      |
+--------+--------------+---------+-----+
| 1      | admin        | admin         | 
+--------+--------------+---------------+
```

But in my opinion it shouldn't show the result. I noticed that sql query checks how many strings are in every column name. When i 1 letter too much or too less then shows nothing.

In that second query case:

```
SELECT * FROM `logins` WHERE USERNAME = "Maxiking1991" AND PASSWORD = "#maxiking1991$";
```

Then show below result:

```
+--------+--------------+---------+-----+
|ID_LOGIN| USERNAME     | PASSWORD      |
+--------+--------------+---------+-----+
| 2      |MaxiKIng1991  |#MaxiKIng1991$ | 
+--------+--------------+---------------+
```

But it shouldn't show that too.

Is that possible to pay attention to lowercase and uppercase letters in values in that mysql queries? any ideas? I have difficulty to search any solution on it. Thx for any help and advice.

Comment: Use where upper(UserName) = 'Admin' or lower(UserName) = 'admin';

Comment: @ArunKumar i've tried with upper and lower query too. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use This Case Sensitive Query like this

```
select * from logins where BINARY USERNAME='admin';
```

If you used 'Admin' instead of 'admin'.It will not match and it produce empty set.